# matching font size in ListView and TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have implemented "endless" scrolling in my app. I use these layouts (they are pretty standard)

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frag_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Footer layout that is shown when downloading more content:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center">
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/msg_loading"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works fine, except "Loading" text in the text view is very small. What is the right way to do so font size in the TextView would match ListView's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look at the layout the list items are using. For example, if you are using the [simple_list_item_1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml), the corresponding `textAppearance`should be `textAppearanceListItemSmall`

Comment: this is available only for API 14, not 11. is there a way to find out what appearances are available for the current API?

Comment: You could circumvent this API limit by declaring your own layout for both the list items and then setting the same textSize to the loading TextView

Comment: i ended up in creatin my custom list view, so i don't use the standard font sizes now